# Making a 2 by 2 board centered

Tags: python, list, whitespace

Say I have a list:

`nlist = [0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0]`

And I have some code:

```
def drawBoard():
    count = 0
    for i in range(16):
        print('|',nlist[i], end = ' ')
        count += 1
        if count == 4:
            print("|\n-----------------")
            count = 0
    print("")
```

And this code displays the list like this:

```
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
-----------------
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
-----------------
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
-----------------
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
-----------------
```

Right now the board looks fine but say I had a value like 128 instead of 1 of the zeros. That would unalign the board and make it look a little messy but when I get a whole bunch of numbers the board will just look plain out messy like this:

```
| 128 | 0 | 4096 | 0 |
-----------------
| 64 | 0 | 0 | 128 |
-----------------
| 2048 | 0 | 0 | 8192 |
-----------------
| 0 | 0 | 64 | 0 |
-----------------
```

And now the board looks messed up and my lines under each number don't reach the end. How can I make the board look something like this(maybe change up the spacing between the straight lines) so that it doesn't look messy anymore:

```
| 128  | 0 | 4096 |   0  |
--------------------------
|  64  | 0 |  0   | 128  |
--------------------------
| 2048 | 0 |   0  | 4096 |
--------------------------
|  0   | 0 |  64  |  0   |
--------------------------
```

Comment: Look up how to format Python output, specifying five digits for each integer.  I expect that will be enough; hardly anyone hits 6 digits on the 2048 game.

Comment: I already tried using format and looked it up. I can't find any solution.

Comment: Then you post *that* code, rather than what you have now; that would show the attempt you've made, and give us a much shorter path to solving your problem.  :-)

Comment: Um I already deleted the format code since it was not working and I wan't to make this program so that the size eventually increases as your number tile goes higher and doesn't just start at a length of 5(If that is possible).

Comment: I have edited my answer to contemplate the "tighter columns" case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the maximum width for each column first, and then use string formatter to pad each number with the maximum width for that column, center aligned. The width of the row divider is just the sum of all the column widths plus 5 column dividers.

```
nlist = [128,0,4096,0, 64,0,0,128, 2048,0,0,8192, 0,0,64,0]
def drawBoard():
    widths = [max(len(str(nlist[row * 4 + col])) for row in range(4)) + 2 for col in range(4)]
    width = sum(widths) + 5
    count = 0
    for i in range(16):
        print('|{:^{width}}'.format(nlist[i], width=widths[i % 4]), end = '')
        count += 1
        if count == 4:
            print("|\n" + '-' * width)
            count = 0
    print("")
drawBoard()
```

This outputs:

```
| 128  | 0 | 4096 |  0   |
--------------------------
|  64  | 0 |  0   | 128  |
--------------------------
| 2048 | 0 |  0   | 8192 |
--------------------------
|  0   | 0 |  64  |  0   |
--------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

The code below finds the length of the largest number in the list and then adds padding to the sides of every number accordingly. After that we print every line by iterating over the list 4 steps at a time.

In:

```
L = [128,0,4096,0,64,0,0,128,2048,0,0,4096,0,0,64,0]

m = len(str(max(L))) + 2
L = [ str(x).center(m,' ') for x in L]
step = 4

for i in range(0,len(L),step):
    s = '|' + '|'.join(L[i:i+step]) + '|'
    print(s)
    print('-'*len(s))
```

Out:

```
| 128  |  0   | 4096 |  0   |
-----------------------------
|  64  |  0   |  0   | 128  |
-----------------------------
| 2048 |  0   |  0   | 4096 |
-----------------------------
|  0   |  0   |  64  |  0   |
-----------------------------
```

If you want larger or smaller tables, just change the value of the step.

In:

```
L = [128,0,4096,0,64,0,0,128,2048,0,0,4096,0,0,64,0]

m = len(str(max(L))) + 2
L = [ str(x).center(m,' ') for x in L]
step = 8

for i in range(0,len(L),step):
    s = '|' + '|'.join(L[i:i+step]) + '|'
    print(s)
    print('-'*len(s))
```

Out:

```
| 128  |  0   | 4096 |  0   |  64  |  0   |  0   | 128  |
---------------------------------------------------------
| 2048 |  0   |  0   | 4096 |  0   |  0   |  64  |  0   |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

However, if you want the padding to be as tight as possible for every column without looking ugly, things get a little bit more complicated.

In:

```
L = [128,0,4096,0,64,0,0,128,2048,0,0,4096,0,0,64,0]
step = 4

# We calculate the padding for every column and store it in sz[].
# The padding for a column is the same as the minimum padding for its largest element.
sz = []
for index,item in enumerate(L):
    column = [L[i] for i in range(index,len(L),step)]
    padding = len( str( max(column) ) ) + 2
    sz.append(padding)
    if index == step + 1:
        break

# Now we iterate over the columns ( not linearly over the array ) 
# and we apply the appropriate padding we have just found out.
i = 0
while i < step + 1:
    for j in range(i,len(L),step):
        L[j] = str(L[j]).center(sz[i],' ')
    i += 1

# Now simply iterate linearly over the array and print a new line 
# every step.
for i in range(0,len(L),step):
    s = '|' + '|'.join(L[i:i+step]) + '|'
    print(s)
    print('-'*len(s))
```

Out:

```
| 128  | 0 | 4096 |  0   |
--------------------------
|  64  | 0 |  0   | 128  |
--------------------------
| 2048 | 0 |  0   | 4096 |
--------------------------
|  0   | 0 |  64  |  0   |
--------------------------
```